# Counting identical consecutive elements in a list in a continuous manner

Tags: python, list

Given a list `x` of number entries, I aim to find the number of identical consecutive entries, where the identical consecutive entries are taken out once counted. For example, if `x = [4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4]`, the returned solution should be `4`:

```
[4, 3, (1, 1), 3, 2, 4] => (two consecutive entries of 1s are counted: 2)
[4, (3, 3), 2, 4] => (two consecutive entries of 3s are counted: 4)
[4, 2, 4] => (no more consecutive entries: final solution is 4)
```

I can use the `for` loop to count the identical consecutive entries, but efficiently removing the elements and running them continuously until there are no more identical consecutive entries is where I find things tricky.

```
solution = 0

for i in range(len(x)-1):
    if x[i] == x[i+1]:
        solution += 2
        if x[i-1] == x[i+2]:
             solution += 2
...
```

where I know these recursive approaches are only applicable to particular lists. Using `itertools` only 'collapses' the length of the list, which is not something I'm looking for. Is there an optimal way to calculate the number of identical consecutive entries?

Comment: What is the expected result for `[1, 1, 1, 1]`? Should the `1`s be counted as one group or two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a stack. If top (last) elememt of stack is same as current element n in x, anihilate it (pop()). Otherwise, push n into stack. `ans` is not really needed - when the loop ends, `len(x)-len(stack)` is the result.

```
x = [4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4]
stack,ans=[],0
for n in x:
    if not stack or stack[-1]!=n:
        stack.append(n)
    else:
        ans+=2
        stack.pop()
print(ans)
```